# Why use finally?

Tags: language-agnostic, try-catch

Every documentation I can find for the `finally` part of a `try-catch-finally` construct is the same: Code within the `finally` block runs whether or not an exception occurred, and it is useful for putting cleanup code.

My question is... why?

I mean, how is this:

```
try {
    doSomething();
}
catch( e) {
    somethingFailed(e);
}
finally {
    cleanupSomething();
}
```

any better than this:

```
try {
    doSomething();
}
catch( e) {
    somethingFailed(e);
}
cleanupSomething();
```

Put another way, how is `finally` any different to just continuing on?

Comment: In a sentence, "because you're stuck using a language that lacks deterministic destructors."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally is actually *very* useful. It is definitely a worthy tool to have around, as it essentially works to protect resources that *must* be managed without waiting for the garbage collector. There are other uses, but this is its primary one.

Why should we use it though? Why not just place the disposal after the catch statement (assuming all exceptions were caught)?

There is a very good reason for this, and that is for when control leaves the try statement. If this occurs, for any reason, finally will get hit before control leaves. So, for example, if a return, continue, break, goto, or an exception if not caught -- if any of that happens in the try block finally will execute whereas the code in your post will not because control had already left. If that had been an important resource it was just leaked.

Comment: Ah, so `finally` runs even if there's something like `return` inside the `try/catch` parts? That's *very* interesting.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - That is correct. So something like `try{ return "hello"; }finally{ throw new exception("concept"); }` will throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

An exception might be thrown that you don't specify to be caught.

Furthermore, I find this construct useful:

```
  try
  {
       // do something
  }
  finally
  {
      // cleanup, in case an exception occurs, this is always called
  }
```

It guarantees the cleanup code to be called, in case of exceptions that are dealt with on a higher level.

Answer (score 0):

`finally` - in Pascal, for instance - is used **because** of the `try` statement. Here is *why* we use it: sometimes, a try statement will work, but only partially - and, this is, in particular, the reason for the `finally`. Once the `try` is complete after a bad "run", we may be left with partial or incomplete objects that are of no use to us (may corrupt the data; cause memory issues).

If the code fails, we want to get rid of the generated object and free the memory (reducing overhead).

An un-nested `cleanupSomething()` may have unintended consequences, perhaps. Too, it guarantees the `finally` or the cleanup will happen regardless of what happens in the larger or body code (as opposed to `cleanupSomething()`).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:
You want to load a big amount of data, and then process it. After the calculations of `Process_The_Data()` the loaded data is no longer needed.

```
try{
  Load_Big_Data();
  Method_That_Fails_Always();
  Process_The_Data();
}
catch( e)
{
  // we may have no means to handle the exception so let it just pass through
}
finally
{
  Delete_The_Data();
}
```

If you use `finally`, you can be sure the Data gets deleted.
Just calling `Delete_The_Data()` in the `catch`-Block is no alternative because it may be that we do not fail, but want the data to be deleted nevertheless.

If you **don't** use finally, the `Delete_The_Data()`-Method is never called, and you have no way to cleanly free your memory. This is bad.

So in conclusion: You should use `finally` if you `try` something that would create a memory leak if not cleanly deleted.